# Converting Images with Python

Tags: python, image, mqtt

I'm having problems getting images to convert out of bytes/strings/etc. I can turn an image into a string, or a byte array, or use b64encode on it, but when I try decode/revert it back to an image, it never works. I've tried a lot of things, locally converting an image and then reconverting it, saving it under a different name. However, the resulting files will never actually show anything. (black on Linux, "can't display image" on windows)

My most basic b64encoding script is as follows:

```
import base64

def convert(image):
    f = open(image)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    string = base64.b64encode(data)
    convertit = base64.b64decode(string)

    t = open("Puppy2.jpg", "w+")
    t.write(convertit)
    t.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert("Puppy.jpg")
```

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm sure it's a simple solution, but being new to Python, it's been a bit difficult trying to sort things out. 
 If it helps with any insight, the end goal here is to transfer images over a network, possibly MQTT.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit** This is in Python 2.7.
Edit 2** Wow, you guys move fast. What a great intro to the community - thanks a lot for the quick responses and super fast results!

Comment: fix your indentation as currently your code would not even run, also calling a variable and your function the same name is not a good idea

Comment: Editing it to fix the indent, it just didn't copy right. Changing that  name too. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a good idea to give a function and a variable the same name! `convert` in your code.

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: you have to specify the mode in which you open your image. Look at the answer of @Padraic Cunningham -> `f = open(image,"rb")`

Comment: Actually, this code works fine for a jpg image I tried (2.7.10 on Linux x64). But the file should be opened with the correct modes anyway.

Comment: There should be no need to base64 encode for MQTT as the payload is just a byte stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python3, you need to open and write in binary mode:

```
def convert(image):
    f = open(image,"rb")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    string = base64.b64encode(data)
    convert = base64.b64decode(string)
    t = open("Puppy2.jpg", "wb")
    t.write(convert)
    t.close()
```

Using python 2 on linux, simply `r` and `w` should work fine. On windows you need to do the same as above.

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files.

You can also write your code a little more succinctly by using `with` to open your files which will automatically close them for you:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

def convert(image):
    with open(image, "rb") as f, open("Puppy2.jpg", "wb") as t:
        conv = b64decode(b64encode(f.read()))
        t.write(conv)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm in 2.7 but that fixed it. It looks like it's working now. Yay! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aaron, are you using windows?

Comment: For testing it right now, yes. But now that it is sorted out, I will be implementing this on Ubuntu, as well.

Comment: It should work fine on ubuntu just opening with r and w, b only really has meaning when it comes to windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
import base64

def convert(image):
    f = open(image)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = convert("Puppy2.jpg")
    string = base64.b64encode(data)
    convert = base64.b64decode(string)

    t = open("Puppy2.jpg", "w+")
    t.write(convert)
    t.close()
```